# How to get a Rails param that contains special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm tracing the post variables via `params.inspect` and see that I have a param called `birthday(1i)`

How can I grab that into a variable?

I've tried `myvar = param["birthday(1i)]` but that did not work

Is there a normal way to access param hash values by a key that contains special characters? I'm completely new to Ruby so this seems odd.

Answer (score 2):

A parameter named like `birthday(1i)` indicates to me that you are using the Rails `date_select` helper method in the view. When you use the `date_select` helper and have an attribute `birthday` in your model then you should be able to allow that params to be set with a common

```
params.require(:model_name).permit(:birthday)
```

When you are really interested in the `birthday(1i)` part of the param then you can read it with

```
myvar = params[:birthday]['1i']
```